# How do I know if this given function is valid or not?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

I have a function $ℝ → ℝ, f(x) = \exp(\log(x))$. Is this function valid?

I was given the explanation that the function is not valid because the domain is $ℝ$ and if I check the function in the given domain $x ∈ ℝ$, for $x > 0$ $\log(x)$ is defined but for $x \le 0$ $\log(x)$ is not defined. Thus the function $f(x) = \exp(\log(x))$ is not defined for $x \le 0$ and hence the given function is not defined in its domain(i.e $x ∈ ℝ).$

Now, I really don't understand what this means. How do we know that for $x \le0$, log(x) is not defined? How can they conclude this without giving any support to the statement?

Comment: Which definition of $\log$ do you use?

Comment: What do you think the value of $\log(-7)$ is?

Comment: The function is valid. It is not necessary that it is defined on every real number. The logarithms are only defined for positive real numbers since $\log_a(x)=y$ means $x=a^y$ and since $a$ is positive real , this is positive as long as $y$ is real.

Comment: So, the given function is not defined for $x\le 0$, for $x>0$ it is equal to $f(x)=x$

Comment: The [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) is the set of inputs accepted by the function, so you would have change the domain to $(0,\infty)$ to make it valid. If you wanted to allow negative numbers in the domain by using the complex log, then you would need to change the codomain to the complex numbers. Even then you'd still need to exclude $0$ from the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function $log(x)$ is an inverse of exponentiation. That means $x$-coordinates of exponentiation are $y$-coordinates of logarithm, and $y$-coordinates of exponentiation are $x$-coordinates for logarithm.

Furthermore exponentiation $e^x$ does not get negative $y$-values, no matter what $x\in R$ is. Follows that inverse cannot get negative $x$-values.